# React throws an error "Can't assign to property" scrollLeft "on 1: not an object" When trying use ref in custom function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a working animation of an object made with the "useRef" hook. Part of the code in this animation will be repeated several times, so I moved it into a separate function, but when I try to call this function, when rendering the component, I get the error "Can't assign to property" scrollLeft "on 1: not an object" what could be the problem?

Full code on codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-silence-bm6hx?file=/src/scroll.js

[image]

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'

const Scrollable = props => {

    const items = props.items;

    let ref = useRef()

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        isScrolling:false,
        clientX:0, 
        scrollX:0  
    })
    
   const [touchStart, setTouchStart] = useState(0);

   let frameId;
    
    const onMouseDown = e =>{...}
    
    const onMouseUp = e =>{
        if(ref && ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault()

        let touchShift = touchStart - state.clientX
        let rez;
        let shift;

        if(touchShift > 0) {
            shift = 300 - touchShift
            rez = state.scrollX + shift

            if(rez>2100){
                rez =1800
                cancelAnimationFrame(frameId)
            }

            let speed = shift / 20
            let cur = state.scrollX
            
            frameId = requestAnimationFrame(animate)
            animate(cur,speed,rez)
        }
    }


    const animate = (cur, speed,rez) => {
            frameId = requestAnimationFrame(animate)
            cur = cur + speed
            ref.current.scrollLeft = cur.toFixed(2)

            if (Math.round(cur) === rez) {
                cancelAnimationFrame(frameId)
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    scrollX:rez,
                    isScrolling:false,
                })
            }
        }


    useEffect(() =>{
        document.addEventListener('mousedown',onMouseDown)
        document.addEventListener('mouseup',onMouseUp)
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown',onMouseDown)
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup',onMouseUp)
        }
    })
    useEffect(() =>{
    ref.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    return () => {
        cancelAnimationFrame(ref.current)
     },[]})

    return (
        <div className={classes.charPage}>
            <div
                ref={ref}
                onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
                onMouseUp={onMouseUp}>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}


export default Scrollable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you're trying to set a property on a number. In your useEffect you're doing this:

```
ref.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate)
```

requestAnimationFrame returns, according to MDN:

> A long integer value, the request id, that uniquely identifies the entry in the callback list. This is a non-zero value, but you may not make any other assumptions about its value.

But you're also using the same ref for your DOM element. After your useEffect runs it will have set your ref to the rAF id which is a number causing your error when you try to set the scrollLeft property on the ref.

What you can try next to solve this is to use 2 separate refs, one for the requestAnimationFrame and one for your DOM element.

Comment: Is there a similar example? I don't understand how everything is implemented. All I could do was create a new let refAnimation = useRef () and use it in useEffect () instead of ref. But what to fix next, I cannot understand.   Now my component is loading, but the animate () function starts working automatically when the component is loaded and is called an infinite number of times, and not on a click event.

Comment: Or replace the `frameId = requestAnimationFrame(animate)` in your animate function with `frameId = refAnimation.current` that could also be the culprit of the infinte loop. I don't think the frameId is even necessary anymore since you have it stored in the ref.

Comment: I updated the code a bit here. Now the function is run 1 time when the component starts. But the animation itself does not work although the function is called on click. And when trying to refresh the page, it gives an error "ref.current is null".      https://codepen.io/RJDio/pen/abpdgbX

Comment: In this form, everything works well for me. I just want to take out the "animate" function separately so that I can reuse it several times.   https://codepen.io/RJDio/pen/VwPeJpv?editors=1010

Comment: The codepens just contain JS so it's hard to see what's going wrong. You could try putting  it in a codesandbox. The error where "ref.current is null" is normal because your initial ref value is not set, you can fix this by first checking if the ref is set before executing the animation.

Comment: For clarity of the principle of animation. https://ibb.co/DDYJ8Yc

Comment: The square inside can be moved with the mouse. The left animation doesn't work. It works to the right. 'Right' is the old version without a function call. To the left with call. I tried to leave comments to make it easier to figure it out. https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-silence-bm6hx?file=/src/scroll.js

Comment: As far as I understood, the **animat() function** works only 1 time, but it must be called inside itself several times until the condition **" if (Math.round(cur) === rez)"** is fulfilled and then it is interrupted. But why it is called only 1 time, I have not been able to find out yet.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-brown-uiow6?file=/src/scroll.js I made them both work with the separate animate function. The useEffect was not setup correctly and you had to pass the animate func params to the rAF callback for it to work.

Comment: Thank you from the bottom of my heart. Now I will figure out how it works.